# Як правильно вживати слово "контакт"?

Tags: вживання-слів

У словниках слово *"контакт"* позначається як таке, що відноситься до сфери стосунків. А чи можна його вживати в технічному контексті? Наприклад, *електричний контакт*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У слова *контакт* є кілька значень, одне з яких Ви згадали. У СУМ-20:

КОНТА́КТ, у, ч.

1. спец. Стикання двох електричних провідників, що створює умови прохідності струму, а також місце такого стикання. Найпоширенішим типом реле є електромагнітне, в якому контакти замикаються або розмикаються під час зміни стану релейного елемента (з наук.-попул. літ.); Залізні половинки розійшлися, і контакт був порушений (Ю. Смолич); Можна жити, покірно місити свою непокірну глину, міняти перегорілі контакти в недопаяному апараті й чекати, коли з протилежного кута кімнати пролунає буденний голос Славка Костельника: – Василю, тебе до телефону (І. Андрусяк); // Прилад, що здійснює стикання електричних провідників. Завдяки шаруватій будові графіт слугує змащувальним матеріалом, а його електропровідність дає змогу виготовляти електричні контакти й електроди (з наук. літ.); Ніна кинула пускову ручку .. Знову перевірила контакти, заміряла пальне (Є. Кравченко).

**Отже вживання даного слова у технічному контексті можливе.**
Також є безліч статей саме про "*електричний контакт*". Ось одна з [них](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82).